# jqGgrid: mutli-level grouping summary value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My objective is to perform multi-level grouping in jqGrid and add summary footer for each level.

I have used the code in their official website for dynamically change the grouping which I extended to do a dynamic three level grouping.

I have created 3 combobox to choose the column name related to the grouping of each level.

I have achieved the mutli level grouping but I have problem here that the summary footer is per page and not the total sum of all rows in each group.

I have tried several solutions:
one of them, the solution implemented in this link http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary_and_grand_total/index.html but It's not worked for me.

I tried to customize the summaryType function to calculte the sum rows for each group on the client side but I can't.

Now, I have prepared the list grouped by the first level on server side and then I get it in client side to fill the summury footer by using "userdata".
this is my function:

```
var sumArraySearch = [];
var criteria = '';// column name selected  in Combobox to do the grouping
function sumSearch(val, name, record)
{
    if(init == 0){
        //  console.log ($("#griddata").jqGrid('getGridParam','userData').rows);
        var rows = $("#griddata").jqGrid('getGridParam','userData').rows;
        var size = $("#griddata").jqGrid('getGridParam','userData').rows.length;
         for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sumArraySearch[rows[i][criteria]]= rows[i]['brutto'];

         }
         init ++;
     }
    return sumArraySearch[record[criteria]];
}
```

And I have blocked now, if I send 2 lists from server: the first is the data grouped by the first level and the second is the data grouped by the second level how can I get the correct sum for each group since the sum is returned by one function?

**EDIT:**

I have prepared a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nayoumi/d2v0neo5/36/) demo to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: 1) You use `loadOnce: true` instead of `loadonce: true` in your code. You should fix the option. 2) Please include the information about the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).  3) If you use free jqGrid fork, then I'd recommend you to add `forceClientSorting: true`, which extend the option `loadonce: true`. 4) It would be good if you prepare JSFiddle demo, which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you please prepare a working demo with data? Only this way is possible to look for the problem described

Comment: @Oleg: I'm using free jQgrid 4.4.3. Is the solution to upgrade the version to 4.7 ?

Comment: @nayomi: jqGrid 4.4.3 is more as 4.5 years old. "jqGrid" exists till version 4.7. After that Tony Tomov, changed the license agreement, the name of the product to "Guriddo jqGrid JS" and made it **commercial** (see the price [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). I started *alternative fork* under the name "free jqGrid", which is available under MIT/GPL license completely free of charge. Thus "free jqGrid" is *the name of the product*. I recommend you to decide whether to use commercial "Guriddo jqGrid JS" or "free jqGrid" and upgrade to the latest version of the corresponding fork.

Comment: @Oleg: I used the "free jqGrid". I have prepared a jsFiddle  demo using the version 4.15.1. Could you look at it ? https://jsfiddle.net/nayoumi/d2v0neo5/36/

Comment: If you click on "External resources" of the left side of the demo, you will see, which CSS and JS files are already included. You don't need to include the same files in HTML part of the demo. On the other side you need to include `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`) and don't need to include `grid.locale-en.js` at all. Currently you included `grid.locale-en.js` **twice** and not included `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` in External Resources. About your main problem: do you have some problem only with **dynamic** setting of grouping? Moreover I don't understand the goal of `sumSearch`.

Comment: thanks for your replay, the problem is the sum of each group I need it to be the total of all rows of each group  not per page. So, I have create the function **sumSearch** to get the sum from server side.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you want to implement. Look at https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/d2v0neo5/39/. It's very simple and it don't use any  `sumSearch`. It just calculate the sum on the client side. Free jqGrid provides many additional callbacks like [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping2-summaryTypeAsArray.htm), but I'm not sure what you really need.

Comment: In fact, this is my problem, I explain the example of level 1 ="agt", In page 1 the sum for agt "806" = 358.64 and in the second page the sum = 771.60. I'd rather want the sum displayed in the hedaer of the group '806' to be the total (so 358.64+771.60 = 1,130.06) that why I have calculated and sent this value **1,130.06** from server side.

Comment: @Oleg: did you understand what's the goal of sumSearch function ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, which I see: your demo require **dynamic grouping**, where the user choose the order of columns. It makes any server side calculations valueless. If you really have **fixed order of grouping** then you should simplify the structure of `userData` to allow just get the required sum by `agt`, for example,

```
userData: {
    brutto: "1593.2",
    sums: { "455": "462.96", "806": "1130.06" }
}
```

It allows to simplify `summaryType` function to

```
summaryType: function sumSearch(val, name, record, groupInfo) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
    return p.userData.sums[record.agt];
}
```

or

```
summaryType: function sumSearch(val, name, record, groupInfo) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
    return p.userData.sums[groupInfo.keys[0]];
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/d2v0neo5/43/.

If you *really need* that *the user* choose grouping columns and the order of grouping **dynamically** then you will have to calculate the sum *on the client side*. You can use, for example, `p.lastSelectedData` parameter to access full data from all pages in correctly sorted order, examine `p.groupingView.groupField` to know the current oder of grouping columns and to use `groupInfo.keys` array to see all keys of the current group. You will get more complex code, but you can **calculate** the sum locally having the information and return it from `summaryType`.